# What does this time mean in delve goroutine traceback info '[chan receive 463432h58m58.750855794s]'

Tags: go, delve

When debugging golang with delve
I got some info bellow
What does this timestamp mean in "[chan receive 463432h58m58.750855794s]"

Update:
This channel with timestamp get stuck for a long time, and
The other one without timestamp flag works well,

```
Goroutine 49 - User: ./rpc.go:63 main.HandleNewBlocks (0x81c865) [chan receive]
```

Is this a error flag about this timestamp ? Yes 463432h58m58.750855794s is almost 53years after 1970,

```
    Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) goroutines
  Goroutine 1 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 sync.runtime_Semacquire (0x464de5) [semacquire 463465h26m25.377840044s]
  Goroutine 2 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [force gc (idle) 463465h26m35.528189373s]
  Goroutine 3 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC sweep wait]
  Goroutine 4 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC scavenge wait]
  Goroutine 5 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [finalizer wait 463465h26m35.528235536s]
  Goroutine 6 - User: /home/mk/go/pkg/mod/github.com/rjeczalik/notify@v0.9.1/tree_nonrecursive.go:36 github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).dispatch (0x75dd25) [chan receive 463465h26m35.528266856s]
  Goroutine 7 - User: /home/mk/go/pkg/mod/github.com/rjeczalik/notify@v0.9.1/tree_nonrecursive.go:81 github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).internal (0x75e55a) [chan receive 463465h26m35.528281759s]
  Goroutine 10 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC worker (idle) 463419h8m19.327260426s]
  Goroutine 18 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC worker (idle) 463419h8m19.327277505s]
  Goroutine 19 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC worker (idle) 463419h8m19.32728711s]
  Goroutine 34 - User: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362 runtime.gopark (0x43bbb6) [GC worker (idle)]
  Goroutine 36 - User: /home/mk/go/pkg/mod/github.com/woshidama323/go-ethereum@v0.0.0-20220917094545-bac23dd3b501/rpc/client.go:587 github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*Client).dispatch (0x74798c) [select 463454h40m13.82125074s]
  Goroutine 40 - User: /home/mk/go/pkg/mod/github.com/woshidama323/go-ethereum@v0.0.0-20220917094545-bac23dd3b501/rpc/client.go:587 github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*Client).dispatch (0x74798c) [select 463454h40m13.821273107s]
  Goroutine 48 - User: /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:7874 net/http.(*http2ClientConn).RoundTrip (0x6e42b1) [select]
  Goroutine 49 - User: ./rpc.go:63 main.HandleNewBlocks (0x81c865) [chan receive]
  Goroutine 58 - User: ./transferengine.go:234 main.(*TransferEngine).PendingTxMonitor.func1 (0x81eb54) [chan receive 463458h17m48.484520231s]
  Goroutine 66 - User: ./transferengine.go:246 main.(*TransferEngine).PendingTxMonitor (0x81e328) [chan receive 463454h40m13.821351068s]
  Goroutine 1931740 - User: /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:55 net.(*netFD).Read (0x606a49) [IO wait]
  Goroutine 1941680 - User: /usr/local/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:8042 net/http.(*http2clientStream).writeRequest (0x6e5129) [select]
[19 goroutines]
(dlv) goroutine 58
Switched from 0 to 58 (thread 286882)
(dlv) bt
0  0x000000000043bbb6 in runtime.gopark
   at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:362
1  0x0000000000409f6c in runtime.chanrecv
   at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/chan.go:577
2  0x00000000004099d8 in runtime.chanrecv2
   at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/chan.go:445
3  0x000000000081eb54 in main.(*TransferEngine).PendingTxMonitor.func1
   at ./transferengine.go:234
4  0x0000000000468dc1 in runtime.goexit
   at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

Comment: Time since Unix-Date maybe? Rough calculation puts it to ~ 53 years elapsed time

Comment: Thanks @ElectronicsStudent Yes, it is indeed time interval from 1970 ,I update the question, because this channel with timestamp get stuck , Is such timestamp a error flag ?

Comment: What does "channel get stuck" exactly mean?

Comment: No any output from channel ,and network works well ,So i guess something wrong with my code, Trying to use dlv to debug this issue,
Of course not sure if the  channel is indeed the root cause.